# VueX Getter not running after Mutation

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have wired up VueX and the Mutations are working correctly, however, the Getter method isn't running again. I'm using VueJS with TypeScript without using the TS class component syntax.

My code is as follows:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    Started: false
  },
  getters: {
    getStarted(state): boolean {
      console.log(state.Started)
      return state.Started;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setStarted(state, payload): void {
      console.log("mutated", payload)
      state.Started = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

I am committing the mutations in child component correctly like so

```
emitStartedClicked(): void {
  console.log("from child clicked");
  this.$store.commit("setStarted", false);
}
```

I listen to the getter in parent component like so:

```
computed: {
    getStarted(): void {
      console.log("gottem");
      return this.$store.getters.getStarted;
    }
  }
```

I trigger the mutation on a button click from a child component and hope to execute the getter in it's parent component's computed properties.

My console output is as follow: 
[image: Img of Console output]

As you can see, on initial page load, the getter in the computed property seems to be working however, after button clicks which trigger the mutation, there are no updates from the getter.
What is the issue here?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried setting state.Started to something other than false?

Comment: no, why should I try that?

Comment: oh it worked... I set it to true and it worked

Comment: Good to hear. It was false to start with and then this.$store.commit("setStarted", false); just updates it to false

Comment: I understand now, the getter wasn't firing because I initialized state as false and was setting it to false in my mutation as well... so I suppose there's some VueX logic in place that doesn't fire the getter if the state's value doesn't change

Comment: You may post it as an answer

Comment: Done. I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting state.Started to something other than false?

It was false to start with and then this.$store.commit("setStarted", false); just updates it to false